# How to resolve external API latency while calling from Azure deployed application?

Tags: azure, http, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

Info :
I have below 2 method which is part of  Web API (not core API) and it is deployed in Azure

Method 1 :

```
public async Task<bool> ProcessEmployee(list<employee> EmployeeList)
                    var tasks = new List<Task<EmployeeResponseModel>>();

                    HttpClient localHttpClient = new HttpClient(); 
                    localHttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
                    

                    foreach (var employee in EmployeeList) // **having 1000 calls** 
                    { 
                     tasks.Add(GetAddressResponse(employee.URL,localHttpClient)); 
                    } 
                    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
          }
```

Method 2 :

```
    private async Task<EmployeeResponseModel> GetAddressResponse(url, HttpClient client)
{
        var response = new EmployeeResponseModel();
        try
        {

            
            using (HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await client.GetAsync(**url**))
            {

                if (apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var res= await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeResponseModel>(res);
                   
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return response;
    }
```

**If i monitor from Azure -> Diagnose and Solve Problem -> Web App Slow all external API calls is showing latency issue**

[image]
[image]

But if i am calling same external API from Postman is is quite fast and having less latency

[image]

1. method 1 and method 2 is part of one web api and it is deployed on Azure AppService.
2. getAddress is external API which is been deployed in other environment and don't have much information
3. if we are calling external API i.e 'getAddress' from 1) we are facing  high latency more than 5 sec.
4. if we are calling external API i.e 'getAddress' from Postman we receive response in 303 ms.

Comment: As you said that you exposed 2 web api and they both have different latency in postman and app insights. Could you pls add details on where you deployed your api project? And how you called these api(via postman and what else)? For example, using postman calling domain:port/greeting cost 305ms to get response while using another program which deployed in another country cost 5000ms to get response.

Comment: By the way, did you meet the problem that your api have high latency and you wanna to find the way to solve it? Or you just wanna to figure it out why postman and app insights have different behavior for latency?

Comment: 1) method 1 and method 2 is part of one web api and it is deployed on Azure AppService.

2) getAdress is external API which is been deployed in other enviornment (not have much information)

3)  if we are calling external API i.e 'getAdress' from 1) we are facing  high latency more than 5 sec.

4) if we are calling external API i.e 'getAdress' from Postman we receive response in 303 ms.

Comment: Basically, I think you could debug your code in localhost to check if the latency has relationship with the code. Because you have low lantency with postman but you didn't mention if you code has long lantency when running locally. And if it's ok for running locally, I think you may need to check the location of the service plan. The location decides the place where your app will deploy. If your position far away from the app service's location, I think it will affect the calling time. Could you pls check it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/kieKg.png

Comment: Is there any progress sir?

Comment: thanks for reply, i am busy with other priority work once configure localhost will update you

Comment: Sure, and pls allow me to post my assumption below.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/tls-handshake-errors-and-connection-timeouts-maybe-it-8217-s-the/ba-p/400501

Comment: https://www.nimaara.com/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it results from the location of the service plan.

If the location of the service plan is far away from you position, it may cause the latency. But it can't rule out other possibilities, so my suggestion is debug in localhost first to rule out the possibility of the code.